# copy a complete section in HTML/PHP

Tags: php, jquery

```
<section id="123">
    <div id="456">
        some Data Here
    </div>
</section>
```

I am a beginner to this and I need to copy data from section and div with their respective ids and use it some where else in my code. Please Help. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Actually i am accessing the div and section with ids. So what can i do to make sure my code works fine. 
Thanks.

Comment: what you mean by copy.?  please explain what you want to do a little more.

Comment: get html by copy?then use `html()`

Comment: actually i am updating the section 123 with some data. when i update this section my previous data  is overwritten. I want to reset my section with a function or something like that to its original contents.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
var htmlstring = $("#123").html();
```

[`.html()` Function in jquery](http://api.jquery.com/html/)

Comment: why its not working. just use `alert()` and see. Im using it

Answer (score 0):

Put your HTML in a php variable , and use it as you want

```
 $div = '<section id="123">
        <div id="456">
            some Data Here
        </div>
    </section>';
```